# The method was called on null error flutter Hive

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

Opening the box

```
var savedList;

Future initiateHive() async {
    ///Creating a HiveBox to Store data
    savedList = await Hive.openBox('Musicbox');
}
```

The function to put data to hive

```
var songFav = SongPlayList()..songInfo = songs[currentIndex].id;

print(songs[currentIndex].id);

savedList.put(songs[currentIndex].id, songFav);
```

The error is

> Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'put' was
> called on null.

Comment: did you register the adapter for your box...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that `savedList.put(songs[currentIndex].id, songFav);` is called before `initiateHive()` finishes execution since `initiateHive()` is asynchronous so `savedList` is still null

you can do something like:

```dart
if (savedList != null){
    savedList.put(songs[currentIndex].id, songFav);
}
```